# How ToSetup a Python Flask Server in IONOS?

Tags: python, flask, ssh, sftp, ionos

I have an ionos server, and I am trying to run a python flask server on it. I connected to it via a Linux Terminal with ssh, however doing `python3 main.py` runs it locally:
[image]

I am new to this, am I doing something wrong? I logged into the ssh with the username and password IONOS gave me in the Web Hosting Essential Page.

[image]

I connected to it with SFTP and added this python code in a file named `main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return "Hello, world"

app.run()
```

This runs it locally, but I can't figure out how to run it on my site. I think I am doing this completely wrong. I tried following the IONOS tutorials, but they don't work.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access it by using a web browser in your computer:
http://*your_server_ip*:5000
If it can be accessed, everything is good. You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) to deploy it (you can choose a different version same with your version's sever near the top of the tutorial)
If it cannot be accessed, maybe your server IP is a shared IP. Ask IONOS, or use other suppliers such as [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Flask does require a server to run (apache 2 or Nginx) if you run just app.py you will launch flask server locally which is meant to be used as a way to quickly modify your server files without taking down ur web server. I highly recommend Apache2 as it’s fairly simple to use and very reliable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).